# Concourse Bosh deployment on OpenStack creates VMs for workers with no persistent_disk key-value defined

Tags: openstack, concourse, cf-bosh

I am doing a Concourse Bosh deployment on OpenStack, and I am having an issue where it assigns a volume for each worker and web instance even though  I have not defined the key-value for persistent_disk on worker or web. As per bosh docs, the default should be `persistent_disk: 0` = no volume. I am leveraging on https://github.com/concourse/concourse-bosh-deployment.

If I explicitly make persistent_disk: 0, then no volumes are assigned as expected, so assume that the default should have changed from https://bosh.io/docs/persistent-disks/#persistent-disk.

```
- type: replace
  path: /instance_groups/name=web/persistent_disk?
  value: 0

- type: replace
  path: /instance_groups/name=worker/persistent_disk?
  value: 0
```

Where would that default be changed?

Answer (score 0):

There is no property that let you set a default persistent disk size for all deployments: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/blob/master/jobs/director/spec

`0` is hardcoded: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh/blob/master/src/bosh-director/spec/unit/deployment_plan/persistent_disk_collection_spec.rb

You can use `persistent_disk_type: default` and define your default in cloud config:

> `persistent_disk_type` [String, optional]: A valid disk type name from the cloud config.

---

BTW, I think that is more intuitive to remove a persistent disk property than set persistent disk size to 0 bytes:

```
- type: remove
  path: /instance_groups/name=web/persistent_disk?
```

https://bosh.io/docs/cli-ops-files/#ops